# Min value for input in Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want to create a simple money input with [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

The money field should have a minimum value of 0, so that a user cannot enter a value less than 0.

However I don't know how to define min value with simple form.

I wonder if it's possible.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Definitely!  The (simplified) HTML for the form you want looks something like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" min="0" step="any" name="amount">
</form>
```

Notice the two really important properties on the input field: `min` is set to 0, because you don't allow negative numbers, and `step` is set to `any`, because you want to allow decimals in.  If you only wanted even dollar amounts, you could set `step="1"`, for example.  Also, if you wanted to set a max value you could with the `max` attribute.

**Important Note:** this only performs validation on the client side.  It's possible to override this if you know what you're doing, so make sure you still validate that the input sent with this form is valid on the server.

I'm not a Ruby guy, but reading through the [Simple Form docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), I think this should work:

```
<%= simple_form_for @transaction do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :amount, input_html: { min: '0', step: 'any' } %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Assuming amount is an number type in your model, it will automatically make an input[type=number] for you.

Comment: This isn't working in the newer versions. Try something like `in: 1.0..200.0, step: 1`. An example is displayed in the answer below.

Answer (score 8):

`simple_form` will set the input attributes based on the model's validations, which means that your client-side and server-side validations will match and cover users with fancy modern browsers that support HTML5's new input types and attributes, and users with older browsers that do not.

For example, given this model:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :amount, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 }
end
```

And this view:

```
<%= simple_form_for Purchase.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :amount %>
<% end %>
```

The resulting markup will look something like this (I've removed some attributes for clarity):

```
<form …>
  <div>
    <label for="purchase_amount">Amount</label>
    <input id="purchase_amount" name="purchase[amount]"
           min="1"  step="1" type="number" />
  </div>
</form>
```

As noted in another answer, if you want to override the default attributes you can use the `input_html` option when calling `#input`:

```
<%= simple_form_for Purchase.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :amount, input_html: { min: 0 } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've put exactly `validates :amount, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 }` on my model's attribute and this doesn't add the `min` attribute in the view to the `amount` input. Could you post a link to documentation confirming your answer?

Comment: It's not exactly documentation, but here's a test case from simple_form that confirms this functionality: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/749c926140ee383e8249f15d1846f5287c5a4c46/test/inputs/numeric_input_test.rb#L30-L36

Answer (score 6):

For @georgebrock's answer to work, in simple_form.rb (or whatever name you do use, could be simple_form_bootstrap.rb) you need to change:

```
b.optional :min_max
```

To:

```
b.use :min_max
```

For the wrapper that's being used to draw the input.

The "optional" means simple form will use the component but will not lookup automatically, letting you to specify :min and :max params on the input manually.

Comment: For this to work you need to use `greater_than_or_equal_to` and `less_than_or_equal_to` numericality validator otions, not `greater_than` or `less_than`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer of @alexander-s is normally right.

However, I had an issue with simple_form.rb being run over by simple_form_bootstrap.rb that they instruct you NOT to change. It lists `b.optional :min_max` many places.

Instead of the global setting of `b.use :min_max` mentioned by @alexander-s, I used

```
<%= f.input :amount, min_max: true %>
```

This is better as it reuses the min number set in your model.