# Check for zero or negative values in helpers?

Tags: ruby, helper, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I wrote the following `rspec` feature to check if entered value equal to zero or negative:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature 'Users can create new credits' do

  before do
    visit credits_url
    click_link 'New Credit'
  end

  scenario 'with zero value' do
    fill_in 'Amount', with: 0.00
    click_button 'Create Credit'

    expect(page).to have_content 'Credit has not been created.'
  end

  scenario 'with negative value' do
    fill_in 'Amount', with: -100.00
    click_button 'Create Credit'

    expect(page).to have_content 'Credit has not been created.'
  end

end
```

I think, to have passed this test I will need to write `helpers/credit_helper.rb` for that, but can't figure out where to start from.

Maybe I'm wrong regarding helpers?

Comment: well you are already requiring rails_helper, why not write a simple function in it that takes a number or input  (lets call it num) and returns `num === 0 || num > 0` which will return true if that is the case and false otherwise? then in the test set up a conditional that executes the code you have if the return from the helper method is true. OR you could just set up that conditional `if num == 0 || num > 0 ` right there in the test. just a thought.

Comment: @HolyMoly I think what you explained might apply only the test side and won't I still able to add 0 or negative values in the app itself?

Comment: that is true, but i thought you were just testing to see if a value equal to or less than zero had been entered.client-side  you can probably add some validation in the form itself if you want to prevent a number less than 1

Comment: I'm making an app using TDD/BDD first approach. I'd like to have some clear examples how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by having the following model `credit.rb`:

```
class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 }
end
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26257029/1745902

Answer (score -1):

Well heres an approach, totally untested.

```
controller:

def create
 @payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
 amount=@payment(params[:amount])

  if (amount > 0)
     payment.save
  else 
     flash[:error] = 'Credit has not been created.'
  end

end
```

This is just an idea to an approach. You will have to render the flash error to the page using something like:

```
<% if flash[:error] -%>
  <p ><%=h flash[:error] %></p>
<% end -%>
```

This would not prevent the user from entering an amount less than 1, it is simply testing for it, and rendering the 'Credit has not been created.' content that it seems your test is looking for. If you want to PREVENT it then as I said you could do some sort of validation on the form directly.